# MYSQL: Select row based on ranking by joining tables

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have three tables as given:

**country**

```
Id  | code   |  name
-------------------------
1   | DE     |  Germany
2   | IT     |  Italy
3   | ES     |  Spain
4   | FR     |  France
```

**currency**

```
Id  | code     |   name          
-------------------------------
1   |  EUR     |   Euro            
2   |  USD     |   US Dollors      
3   |  CAD     |   Canadian Dollors
```

**country_currency**

```
country_id    |  currency_id |  ranking
-------------------------------------------
1             |  1           |  5    
1             |  2           |  10      
1             |  3           |  15      
2             |  1           |  5      
3             |  1           |  10      
4             |  2           |  5      
4             |  3           |  10
```

As you see in third table, `country_id => 1` has three assigned currencies with different ranking. In other words, Germany has three assigned currencies (EUR and USD and CAD). So, EUR should be display with Germany because it has 5 ranking which is minimum.

---

For Italy and Spain , only `currency_id => 1` is assigned (EUR). So, EUR should be displayed for Italy and Spain.

---

For France, `currency_id => 2` and `currency_id => 3` (USD and CAD) but USD has minimum ranking with France row. So, USD should be displayed with France.

---

**Expected Result**

```
country         | currency
---------------------------
Germany         |  EUR                 
Italy           |  EUR                 
Spain           |  EUR                 
France          |  USD
```

**My query**

```
select country.name, currency.code from country_currency 
inner join country on country.id = currency_country.country_id 
inner join currency on currency.id = currency_country.currency_id
order by ranking asc
group by country_id
```

It doesn't work at all. Any one can help me to fix this query?

**[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1eb2c7)**

Comment: **Please share the SQL query you are working on and somebody will help fix it.**

Comment: ok i will do it now.

Comment: can two currency tie with same min value for a country? like in france both have 5?

Comment: No. in my table it will be always different. Assume they are different than each other. but with same min value. we can pick any one.

Comment: Added SQLFIDDLE to OP's question: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1eb2c7

Comment: Just to explain why your query doesn't work: GROUP BY comes first, so you want one row per country_id. You get the according country name and arbitrarily one of its currency codes. Then comes ORDER BY. You order by ranking which is also arbitrarily one of each currency's rankings. Remember: GROUP BY comes with aggregation functions. You'd need a function to get the currency for the minimum ranking, such as Oracle's KEEP FIRST. MySql doesn't offer such function, so you must find another way.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT name AS country, 
      (SELECT c3.code
       FROM country_currency AS c2 
       INNER JOIN currency AS c3 ON c3.id = c2.currency_id
       WHERE c1.id = c2.country_id 
       ORDER BY ranking LIMIT 1) AS currency
FROM country AS c1;
```

The above query makes use of a single correlated sub-query in order to get the `code` value of currency having the minimum ranking per country.

**Note:** If more than one currencies share the same minimum ranking for a specific country, then one of them is *arbitrarily* chosen.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de8540/1)

Comment: It wasn't the awe-inspiring alias names, though, that made me upvote your answer ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i understand about same minimum ranking but it will not happen in my table.

Answer (score 2):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a099/7

```
SELECT c.name, curr.name
FROM country c
LEFT JOIN country_currency cc
ON cc.country_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN country_currency cc_min
ON cc_min.country_id = cc.country_id
  AND cc.ranking > cc_min.ranking
LEFT JOIN currency curr
ON curr.id = cc.currency_id
WHERE cc_min.ranking IS NULL;
```